# Cannot open display while running X Apps as another user

Tags: linux, x11, rhel, xterm, xrdp

I am currently using **X11RDP** to connect to a **RHEL 6.5 endpoint**, as root user. All X apps work fine, and directed properly to the right display (say 11.0).

Now if I switch to another user (*su - user1*), then I try to open any X app (say xterm) it will be **unable to open the display** (even though it is also 11.0).

I do not believe the problem to be with *xauth* (magic cookies, etc), or the *DISPLAY* environment variable not being set correctly, or allowing connection with *xhost +*; but rather something with **XRDP**.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem was actually in how x11rdp was starting.

It starts the x server with *-nolisten tcp*.

If that part is commented out in **/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini** for **x11rdp** then the problems described above will be gone.

Hope this helps other people experiencing the same problems.