# Python - Tkinter over xrdp Display issue

Tags: python, tkinter, remote-access, xrdp

I am learning about Python3 scripting/programming with this config:

- My PC on win10
- remote PC under my tv with Debian 9 on it.

I installed `xrdp` to get a remote graphical UI to play around with Tkinter.

I wrote this very simple script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#coding: utf-8

from tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()

label = Label(fenetre, text="Hello World")
label.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

But I hit an issue:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":10.0"

I understand that's linked to xrdp because if I try it physically on the pc it works well.
Any idea or workaround? :/

Thank you !

Comment: So are you remoted into your Debian pc and trying to run python from there? Are you using SSH?

Comment: Not SSH but xrdp, compatible with windows remote desktop manager. Trying to play with graphical objects could by a little handy in SSH ;p

Comment: Related [cannot-open-display-while-running-x-apps-as-another-user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063218/cannot-open-display-while-running-x-apps-as-another-user) and [xrdp.ini](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-xrdp.ini/)

Comment: That didn't change anything sadly :/
But the title of the topic enlighted me a bit, it may indeed be an user related problem because I launch the xrdp session as joe and play in the terminal as root, investigations continue !

Answer (score 0):

I used this with Python3.10 on Ubuntu 20.4 with `xrdp` and `hyper-v` running on Windows 11 and it works.

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(window, text="Hello World")
label.pack()

window.mainloop()
```